# Disable open in new tab or control/middle click for certain links?

Tags: ajax

I'd like to stop certain links from opening in a new tab if the users tries to do so  (I think Gmail does this somehow). It is to stop people loading pages meant to be loaded by ajax on their own.

Comment: Hey, just out of curiosity, what was your reason behind wanting this disabled?  You left right click --> New tab enabled?  If so what is it about middle click specifically that made you want to disable it?  Thanks!

Comment: @RyanWiancko - same question - most annoying thing and I just came here because yet another site prevented me from opening hyperlink in new tab while holding cmd/ctrl... this is retarded :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.no_new_tab').mousedown(function(e){
    if(e.which==2) { // 2 is middle click
        //console.log('new tab attemp');
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    }
});
```